# "Восстановить В бюджетном учете" или "Восстановить НА бюджетном учете"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Восстановить В бюджетном учете или восстановить НА бюджетном учете?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно: **восстановить (в чем? где?) в бюджетном учете.**

**Бюджетный учет** ― учет всех доходов бюджета, источников финансирования дефицита бюджета, расходов бюджета, а также операций, осуществляемых в процессе исполнения бюджета.

**Пример:** Комиссия приняла решение восстановить  в бюджетном учете (списать с учета) неучтенное (числящееся неправомерно) имущество.

**Предлог НА** используется в выражении "находиться на учете, на бюджетном учете".

Покупать газеты нам было не по карману, даже 25-50 центов их тогдашней стоимости были у нас **на строгом бюджетном учёте** каждого дня. [Владимир Голяховский. Русский доктор в Америке (1984-2001)]

Answer (score 3):

**Бюджетный учёт** - специфически бухгалтерское понятие, оно во многих случаях фигурирует как синоним документов бюджетной отчётности (или бюджета), **в** которых можно что-то *отразить*, *восстановить* после исключения **из** них и т. п. - как правило, в форме денежных средств, складывающихся в общую сумму. Поэтому в данной области сложилась фразеология **с предлогом "в"**, не связанная с понятиями "**поставить на учёт - снять с учёта - восстановить на учёте**" где-либо (в качестве кого-л.), характерными для сущностей, учитываемых строго индивидуально (например, людей). Примеры юридических документов, где учёт фигурирует не в бухгалтерском смысле и применяется выражение "**восстановить на учёте**":

https://rospravosudie.com/court-orlovskij-oblastnoj-sud-orlovskaya-oblast-s/act-103832709/

http://yurbu.ru/sudebnayapraktika/po-zhilishchnim-sporam/51-reshenie-suda-o-vosstanovlenii-na-uchjote-nuzhdayushchikhsya-v-uluchshenii-zhilishchnykh-uslovij.html